# search for ids half string and half number

Tags: mysql

I have old data stored in DB. Unfortunately this data is being stored very silly. id is being stored half string and half integer. Ids stored like this:

```
OBE19001
OBE19003
OBE20000
```

**I want to search for Ids > OBE30000**

I run the normal search:

```
SELECT id FROM orders WHERE order_id>OBE30000
```

it gave me this error

```
Error: Unknown column 'OBE30000' in 'where clause'
```

Comment: Can I get the accepted answer then please?

Comment: yes waiting... 12 min you need to wait buddy :)

Comment: A better idea is to fix your data.

Comment: this data is 10 years old. and there are many tables which is joined to this table. and it is running every seconds by many users. I have already start new system with new tables...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT id FROM orders WHERE order_id>'OBE30000'
```

Answer (score 1):

You forget to put single quotes

```
SELECT id FROM orders WHERE order_id>'OBE30000'
```